# sort doesn't like my predicate

Tags: c++

I am trying to sort a vector by passing the first and last item and passing a bool predicate. Cannot for the life of me figure out what i am doing wrong.  Suspect its lack of understanding of classes. But its really got me stumped.

Am going through accelerated c++ and am on chapter 4. Spent a good while reading around but am not getting anywhere. Probably doesn't help me that i am doing things in classes either so i can keep chapters side by side.

The error i am getting is

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

on the line that calls sort.

So in a header (Ch4) i have the following (I have edited this code down for your sanity - the includes etc seem to be happy - the header and code are in separate files and am using vs2013 so its sorted all that out for me)

```
class Ch4
{
public:
    int Ch4::Run();
    struct Student_Info;
    bool compare(const Student_Info& x, const Student_Info& y);
}
```

Then in the class:

```
struct Ch4::Student_Info
{
    string name;
    double midterm, final;
    vector<double> homework;
};

int Ch4::Run()
{
    vector<Student_Info> students;
    ... code that populates it
    sort(students.begin(), students.end(), compare);
}

bool Ch4::compare(const Student_Info& x, const Student_Info& y)
{
    return x.name < y.name;
}
```

when i change that line to

```
sort(students.begin(), students.end(), Ch4::compare);
```

I get an error saying its missing an argument list - but in my list of overloads it doesn't show one that takes an argument list.

So i follow its advice and use it as a reference and i get back to the original error message.

So I am confused about 2 things:
1) why doesn't my code work - how to fix it
2) What are these error messages telling me, why do they seem to talk about an overload that doesn't exist or is hidden from me?

Comment: Declare compare function as static.

Comment: It has to be a *functor* - either a function pointer, a lambda, or a type with overloaded `operator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compare` is a non-static method

Make it `static`:

```
static bool compare(const Student_Info& x, const Student_Info& y);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `compare` function is non-static. You either need to make it a free function, or else make it static.